# Document C code containing state machines

Tags: c, doxygen, graphviz, state-machine, fsm

I've written C code containing a state machine [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTr0S.png). Now I'm looking for a way to generate a html file documenting that state machine like [2].

I've looked at doxygen [3]. It can extract texts, callgraphs and the like,  but it cannot generate state machine diagrams.
I've looked at Graphviz [4]. It can generate state machine graphs, but it cannot combine text and the graph in one html file. 
I've found a Doxygen Preprocessor [5], that claims to be able to document state machines, but the last update is from 2009

Does anybody know a system that can extract both text and diagrams from source code, or specially crafted comments in the code, and that is actively developed?

**Edit 1**
I've not expressed my question as clearly as I should have. I would like to figure out a workflow that enables me to document and verify the C code I make for a product based on a microcontroller.

I would like to enable my users with limited to no programming knowledge to be able to understand what I'm about to implement in C code, so there's a higher chance that the C code I make is actually what the user wants.

So far I came up with this workflow:

1) Me and the user sit down, and discuss what all the fault conditions are that can happen, and what my program should do in response to those. This is stored in a spreadsheet.

2) I convert the spreadsheet from step 1 into one or more state machines. This can be done by pen and paper. When this is done, I let the user check if the state machine is consistent with the spreadsheet.

3) I write the state machine in machine understandable form, and let a program generate the graphical representation of the state machine. I let the user check if this is the same state machine as the version of step 2.

4) I take the machine understandable form of the state machine, and use that to write unit tests for each state and transition of the state machine. I let a co-worker with programming skills check if the unit tests are consistent with the state machine.

5) I write the C code, and tweak it so that it passes all the unit tests.

6) The finished product is tested according to the scenario's from step 1.

While writing this down, I realize there's a lot of manual work in this process that may be done automatically. Do you know of tools that can do this?

SMC [6] as suggested by Fiddling Bits looks promising, but I'm unsure if it can generate a C-file like the one posted under [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTr0S.png). I'm also unsure if I can do a round trip like this: I write the state machine in a .sm file, let SMC generate a C file. I edit the C file, I let SMC update the .sm file, I edit the .sm file, and let SMC update the C file again.

**Edit 2**
I've looked at plantuml as suggested by Marc, but that adds extra complexity in the tools needed to generate the html pages.

I've solved the problem by using the \dot command [7] to embed a graphvid diagram in an doxygen command block. See [8] for the C code.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTr0S.png) the C code

```
typedef enum
{
    stIDLE=0,
    stDONE
} TRXSTATES;

TRXSTATES theState = stIDLE;

void execute (void)
{
    switch (theState)
    {
        case stIDLE:
        {
            theState = stDONE
            break;
        }
        case stDONE:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[2] the desired html page

```
Some smart text about this state machine
+--------+       +--------+
+ stIDLE + ----> + stDONE +
+--------+       +--------+
```

[3] http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html

[4] http://graphviz.org/

[5] https://sites.google.com/site/abudden/doxygen-preprocessor

[6] http://smc.sourceforge.net/

[7] http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddot

[8] the updated C code

```
/** \mainpage
 * Some smart text about this state machine
 * \dot
 * digraph statemachine {
 *      rankdir=LR
 *      node [shape=record, fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=10];
 *      stIdle [ label="Idle" ];
 *      stDone [ label="Done" ];
 *      stIdle -> stDone [ label ="Finished", arrowhead="open", style="solid" ];
 *  }
 *  \enddot
*/
typedef enum
{
    stIDLE=0,
    stDONE
} TRXSTATES;

TRXSTATES theState = stIDLE;

void execute (void)
{
    switch (theState)
    {
        case stIDLE:
        {
            theState = stDONE
            break;
        }
        case stDONE:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: resulting html page]

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a custom implementation if you write your C code yourself (rather than having it generated for you).

Comment: You can look into this: http://smc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You would normally design your state-machine before coding it.  Auto-generating (and round-tripping) code from a diagram is much simpler than _reverse engineering_ arbitrary hand-written code into a diagram since there is more than one way of implementing a state machine and various coding styles to cope with.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to use `plantuml` to code diagrams in text, in `doxygen`.

Example of diagram:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/structpfs__lock.html

Source code for it, look at `@startuml` / `@enduml`

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/perfschema/pfs_lock.h

The diagrams are maintained manually, which allows also to add notes, comments, etc, in the resulting doc.